# Scrape address using BeautifulSoup for Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am having difficulties scraping the address from the following weblink, please help me scrape the address.

http://www.salatomatic.com/d/Revesby+17154+Ahlus-Sunnah-Wal-Jamaah-Revesby

the source code for the weblink above is as follow

```
<td width="100%"><div class="titleBM">Bankstown Masjid </div>Meredith Street, Bankstown, New South Wales 2200</td>
```

I am trying to scrape the value immediatly after `</div>`

my current code is not completed but looks like follow

```
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content1)
div1 = soup1.find('div', {'class':'titleBM'}) #get the div where it's located
span1 = div1.find('</div>')
pos1 = span1.text       

print datetime.datetime.now(), 'street address:  ' , pos1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is the next sibling of the `<div>` element, so use `next_sibling`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import datetime

url1 = 'http://www.salatomatic.com/d/Revesby+17154+Ahlus-Sunnah-Wal-Jamaah-Revesby'

content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content1)
div1 = soup1.find('div', {'class':'titleBM'}) #get the div where it's located
pos1 = div1.next_sibling

print datetime.datetime.now(), 'street address:  ' , pos1
```

Run it like:

```
python2 script.py
```

It yields:

```
2013-12-03 12:55:41.306271 street address:   9-11 Mavis Street, Revesby, New South Wales 2212
```

Answer (score -1):

**This happening because of JavaScript, you should  use selenium webdriver to solve this issue:**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
```

**Find more here** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650999/using-python-with-selenium-to-scrape-dynamic-web-pages)

Comment: I think you were a little quick to jump to selenium on this one. The accepted answer shows how to complete without